# Where can I find openbox logs?

Tags: ubuntu

I have a multi head openbox setup with fglrx as my drive. I chosen openbox from the gnome login screen of 12.10.

My openbox crashes when I click to desktop left or right, but this does not happens always but rarely. Yet loosing all desktop if pretty irritating.

Where can I find crash log of the openbox?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [`openbox` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/openbox). I would start with the `--debug` switch when you invoke it.

*excerpt*

```
--debug            Display debugging output.
--debug-focus      Display debugging output for focus handling.
--debug-xinerama   Split the display into two fake xinerama regions, if 
                   xinerama is not already enabled. This is for debugging 
                   xinerama support.
```

The [Help:Actions](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help%3aActions) reference page might be useful too if you need to dig deeper into what's going on.

Comment: I do not run the openbox, its started from GDM, which might have something to do with the bug. I need the access the logs of the instance ran by GDM.

Comment: Those would be under `/var/log`. But You'll likely need to find under `/etc/` where openbox is being called from `GDM` and add the `--debug` switch there to get more useful logging.